# retrieve data from multiple table with same fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table "ABC_history" which store history having millions of records,
so i am thinking to create month and year wise table like

```
ABC_history_January_2012
ABC_history_February_2012 
ABC_history_march_2012
.
.
.
ABC_history_December_2012
```

i want to fetch data using condition date is `between "2012-01-15" and "2012-02-15"`, 
how can i achieve this using **single query** or is there any other way to store large data?

want to implement same concept of inheritance in postgreSQL. refer for example [Best way to store huge log data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110356/best-way-to-store-huge-log-data)

Comment: If the schema of those tables will be identical, they shouldn't exist as separate entities. What are the reasons for porting it out by month?

Comment: single table have less number of records

Comment: That's not a reason. Set up proper indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a poor data structure.  Unfortunately, the only way to do a generic query is to `union all` the tables together:

```
select *
from ((select * from ABC_history_January_2012) union all
      (select * from ABC_history_February_2012) union all 
      (select * from ABC_history_march_2012) union all
      . . .
      (select * from ABC_history_December_2012)
     ) abch
where date is between '2012-01-15' and '2012-02-15';
```

Very expensive query.

What you want is table partitioning.  This allows you to store one table in multiple "parts".  Each part would be determined by a date range.  Then, any query that uses the date would only read the data that is needed.  You can read more about table partitioning [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html).